# Global installation with npm : @latest version not recommended for global scope?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I recently heard discussion between developers that I didn't understand : 
For `npm` module installation, `@latest` tag should not be used with `--global` option because, with any update it could cause some trouble. Conclusion was : `@latest` can be used peacefully for local installation but a specific version is preferred for global installation.
But I didn't understand explanation.

Comment: PS : begin of post is truncated even when editing so :
Hello everyone

Comment: PPS : it is for angular installation

Answer (score 1):

@latest is used to override any versions listed as dependencies within your package.json.

You shouldn't have a global package.json and therefore there isn't a reason to use @latest because `npm install` will install the latest version by default.

[npm install docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

> `npm install [<@scope>/]<name>`:
>
> Do a `<name>@<tag>` install, where `<tag>` is the "tag" config. (See npm-config. **The config's default value is latest**.)
>
> In most cases, this will install the version of the modules tagged as latest on the npm registry.